# Arduino programmers for hire?

Tags: programming

How do I best connect with Arduino programmers who are willing to design small projects for some extra cash?

Comment: are you talking about Free lancer   ?

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Forum has a [Gigs and Collaborations](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?board=26.0) section where such questions are welcome.